# I have to classify a certain grade into (A,B,C,D,F), but error message doesn't show up

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

When the final grade is above 200, i want an error message to show up but it doesn't, i tried to structure my loop that way but it just doesnt work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Formatter;
public class Lab3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double midtermGrade = 50.0;
    double homeworkGrade = 0.0;
    double finalExamGrade = 50.0;
    double finalGrade = 0.0;

    char letterGrade = ' ';

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter homework grade: ");
    homeworkGrade = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter midterm exam grade: ");
    midtermGrade = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter final exam grade: ");
    finalExamGrade = scan.nextDouble();

    if ((!(homeworkGrade >= 0) || !(homeworkGrade <= 100))) return;
    if (((midtermGrade >= 0) && (midtermGrade <= 100)))

        if ((((!(finalExamGrade > 0) || !(finalExamGrade < 200))))) {


            finalGrade = (finalExamGrade / 200) * 50 + (midtermGrade * .25) + (homeworkGrade * .25); //.25 denotes 25%
        }
    System.out.println("Invalid input. Homework and midterm grades should be between 0 and 100 and the final grade should be between 0 and 200");


            if (finalGrade >= 50) {

                letterGrade = 'P';

            } else if (finalGrade < 50) {
                letterGrade = 'F';
            }

            if (letterGrade == 'P') {

                System.out.println("Student passed the class");

            } else if (letterGrade == 'F') {
                System.out.println("Student failed the class");
            }

        }


}
```

When i put the obnoxiously large numbers, i don't get any message. The debug ends.

Comment: where are you checking the `finalGrade`? or did you mean the final exam grade? Anyway, simplify the expressions `!(a > b)` is the same as `a <= b`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch (assuming you meant its expression, not the whole statement) `homeworkGrade = 10`? `(!(10 >= 0) || !(10 <= 100))` - `(!true || !true)` - `(false || false)` - `false`

Answer (score 0):

I think the ! is interfering with the final grade

Answer (score 0):

i change your code and now it works. here it is:

```
    package test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double midtermGrade = 50.0;
        double homeworkGrade = 0.0;
        double finalExamGrade = 50.0;
        double finalGrade = 0.0;

        char letterGrade = ' ';

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter homework grade: ");
        homeworkGrade = scan.nextDouble();

        if (!(homeworkGrade >= 0) || !(homeworkGrade <= 100)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.Homework grades should be between 0 and 100");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter midterm exam grade: ");
        midtermGrade = scan.nextDouble();

        if (!(midtermGrade >= 0) && !(midtermGrade <= 100)){
            System.out.println("Invalid input.midterm grades should be between 0 and 100");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Enter final exam grade: ");
        finalExamGrade = scan.nextDouble();

        if ((!(finalExamGrade > 0) || !(finalExamGrade < 200))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. final grade should be between 0 and 200");
            return;
        }

        finalGrade = (finalExamGrade / 200) * 50 + (midtermGrade * .25) + (homeworkGrade * .25); //.25 denotes 25%

        if (finalGrade >= 50) {

            letterGrade = 'P';

        } else if (finalGrade < 50) {
            letterGrade = 'F';
        }

        if (letterGrade == 'P') {

            System.out.println("Student passed the class");

        } else if (letterGrade == 'F') {
            System.out.println("Student failed the class");
        }
    }

}
```

You just need to change your package name and class name.

Note: 
- its better to check each input, after the scan. And check if the value is right or not. if the input data is not right, you should return and terminate the program.

Comment: Noted, thank you very much. This is like my 4th time coding so I'm trying to get a hang of it.

Comment: But - I need to have it so that if the finalGrade is above 200 or below 0, the error displays not for each one of them. Illogical, i know but that's how our professor wants it

Comment: in the code that i wrote, you will get the related error. So if the Final grade is not in that specific range, the error related to final grade will show up

Comment: if you don't want to stop the program in case of wrong input, just remove the return statements. in this case, you should put your calculations in a if statement. because it should only calculate when the input data is right